# Original Tzetel Katan Online

Tags: chassidic-rebbe, search

Could someone please point me to where I can find the Tzetel Katan by R' Elimelech of Lizhensk online in the original format? I looked around on HebrewBooks but I couldn't find anything. The closest I came was [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_4266_14.pdf), but it's not complete and I can't seem to find it on the site, only through a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D7%A6%D7%A2%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9C%20%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F&oq=%D7%A6%D7%A2%D7%98%D7%99&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j0l4.2431j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (see the fourth result).

Comment: Whaddaya mean by "format"? D'you mean that it should be in the same layout on the page that he used when he hand-wrote it? Or what?

Comment: @msh210 - I believe I mean that it should be like some of the original prints, like the PDF I linked from HebrewBooks.

Comment: I'd seen that PDF but have no idea what you mean by "like". Can you [edit] your question so people reading it know exactly what you're seeking?

Answer (score 1):

You can buy it here:
[https://www.amazon.com/Tzetel-Katan-Rebbe-Elimelech-Lizhensk/dp/1600913792](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600913792)
Or Here
http://www.israelbookshoppublications.com/store/pc/The-Tzetel-Katan-p1020.htm
Or you can read it online here:
https://www.sefaria.org/Noam_Elimelech,_Introduction,_The_Tzetel_Katan?lang=bi